# How to join on to variable table based on field value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called tracks with with basic data. The important parts are that this table has a column named id and event. The value of the event field is the name of another table. That table has a matching id with a lot of details about what was tracked. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
SELECT id, event, e.*
FROM tracks t
LEFT JOIN $event e ON t.id = e.id
```

The value of event could be one of a hundred different values.

Comment: You need concatenate your query dynamically in your programming language

Comment: Anyway around that?. I'm tying to get all the tracks for the last 60 days and then get the details from the specific event table. I didn't create the structure and trying to avoid doing looping queries.

Comment: Do all the specific table have the same structure (or will you be okay with getting a row from that specific table as a json or something?). There are ways, but looping might be faster.

Comment: They have about a dozen shared properties. Some of the tables have a value and revenue column and those are what I'm trying to get, if they are empty or don't exist that is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you could use inheritance: [PostgreSQL 9.5.1 Documentation: Inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-inheritance.html)

In this case you may have empty parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE events(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    event_type INTEGER,
    ...
);
```

And bunch of children tables

```
CREATE TABLE events_1(event_type INTEGER DEFAULT 1 CHECK(event_type = 1)) INHERITS (events);
CREATE TABLE events_2(event_type INTEGER DEFAULT 2 CHECK(event_type = 2)) INHERITS (events);
...
```

Then you will be able to use queries like:

```
SELECT t.id, t.event_type, e.*
FROM tracks t
JOIN events e on t.id = e.id AND t.event_type = e.event_type;
```

But you have to add all columns to parent if you want request them from parent table.

UPD: you cannot use variable as table name in pure sql. Only way to do it is dynamic code generation (for example in plpgsql).

Comment: You should be able to avoid the extra column by using [`tableoid`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html): `JOIN events e on t.id = e.id AND t.event::regclass = e.tableoid`

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a variable table name in a simple SQL query; one way or another, you need to build and execute a dynamic query string.

If you want to avoid doing this in your application code, you'll need to use PL/pgSQL's [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), which means you'll have to create a function to do it.

If the common fields in your event tables are e.g. `x INT, y INT`, then this should work (though it may not be particularly efficient):

```
CREATE FUNCTION EventTable(TableName TEXT, id INT) RETURNS TABLE (x INT, y INT) AS
$$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT x, y FROM ' || TableName || ' WHERE id = $1' USING id;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT id, event, e.*
FROM t
LEFT JOIN EventTable(event, id) e ON true;
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c424e/1)